# write to mmap'ed output passed to a thread through a struct (C)

Tags: c, struct, pthreads

I'm working on a project to learn about multithreading and getting stuck with writing my output.

The program opens and mmaps a file, performs a series of operations on it, then outputs the result to another mmap'ed file. the parameters are being passed to the threads via a struct.

It reads the input fine, but can't write to the output location. Here are (I think) all of the relevant code segments.

the input and output are mmapped like so:

```
int * ptrin = mmap(NULL, sizeofin, PROT_READ ,MAP_SHARED , a, 0);
int * ptrout = mmap(NULL, sizeofin, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE ,MAP_SHARED , c, 0);
```

The struct is:

```
typedef struct data {
int * in;
int * out;
} threaddata;
```

The function is called in the main like so:

```
    if (pthread_create(&threads[numthreads], NULL, (void *) &func, (void*) &Data) != 0) {
    perror("pthread_create() error");
    exit(1);
```

for now numthreads = 1, so not dealing with race conditions and locks yet.

The function itself handles the struct like:

```
void func( void *ptr ) {
threaddata *Data;
Data = (threaddata *) ptr;

for (i = 0; i < ops; i++) {
        // operations here left out
        Data->out[i] = result;
}
```

iterating through/reading the values at `Data->first[index]` works with no issue! it's just when going to write to the output location, it can't access the memory address.  when running the program, the error isn't a segfault but rather `Bus error (core dumped)`. GDB shows this error:

```
Thread 2 "prog" received signal SIGBUS, Bus error.
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffff751b700 (LWP 58056)]
0x0000000000400b99 in func (ptr=0x7fffffffdec0) at prog.c:49
49                              Data->out[i] = result;
```

And when I try to look at the Data object in gdb, I get this:

```
(gdb) p Data->out[0]
Cannot access memory at address 0x7ffff7ff6000
```

Which tells me it's happening right at the first index, so it's not a problem with too many iterations or something like that.

I'm fairly new to the concept of threads, and even passing structs around. I'm assuming that it has something to do with how my struct is storing the mmap'ed output address. The first version of this code did not use a struct or threading, and was able to write to the output file perfectly. So what about my code is written wrong where it can't access `Data->out` ?

Also, this is my first time posting on SO, so I'm sure my wording is wrong somewhere and the question could have been structured better. Sorry for having it broken up I just figured it would be nicer than posting the entire ~200 lines of code. I welcome any feedback that you have so I do better next time.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SIGBUS` means you're accessing the mapped area *outside* the current size of the file. If you were accessing memory outside the *mapped area*, you would get `SIGSEGV` instead.

What you need to do is to use `ftruncate` to resize the output file to be at least `c` bytes long.